# Erro Java method main is too complex

Tags: java

O meu código está apresentando a seguinte mensagem "method main is too complex" quando eu uso diversas condições no if para analise de repetição de números.
Com menos dados no if funciona, mas preciso de todas essas comparações.

```
//Verifica Repetições
if ((combinacao[0] != combinacao[1])
        && (combinacao[0] != combinacao[2])
        && (combinacao[0] != combinacao[3])
        && (combinacao[0] != combinacao[4])
        && (combinacao[0] != combinacao[5])
        && (combinacao[0] != combinacao[6])
        && (combinacao[0] != combinacao[7])
        && (combinacao[0] != combinacao[8])
        && (combinacao[0] != combinacao[9])
        && (combinacao[0] != combinacao[10])
        && (combinacao[0] != combinacao[11])
        && (combinacao[0] != combinacao[12])
        && (combinacao[0] != combinacao[13])
        && (combinacao[0] != combinacao[14])
        && (combinacao[0] != combinacao[15])
        && (combinacao[0] != combinacao[16])
        && (combinacao[0] != combinacao[17])
        && (combinacao[0] != combinacao[18])
        && (combinacao[0] != combinacao[19])
        && (combinacao[1] != combinacao[2])
        && (combinacao[1] != combinacao[3])
        && (combinacao[1] != combinacao[4])
        && (combinacao[1] != combinacao[5])
        && (combinacao[1] != combinacao[6])
        && (combinacao[1] != combinacao[7])
        && (combinacao[1] != combinacao[8])
        && (combinacao[1] != combinacao[9])
        && (combinacao[1] != combinacao[10])
        && (combinacao[1] != combinacao[11])
        && (combinacao[1] != combinacao[12])
        && (combinacao[1] != combinacao[13])
        && (combinacao[1] != combinacao[14])
        && (combinacao[1] != combinacao[15])
        && (combinacao[1] != combinacao[16])
        && (combinacao[1] != combinacao[17])
        && (combinacao[1] != combinacao[18])
        && (combinacao[1] != combinacao[19])
        && (combinacao[2] != combinacao[3])
        && (combinacao[2] != combinacao[4])
        && (combinacao[2] != combinacao[5])
        && (combinacao[2] != combinacao[6])
        && (combinacao[2] != combinacao[7])
        && (combinacao[2] != combinacao[8])
        && (combinacao[2] != combinacao[9])
        && (combinacao[2] != combinacao[10])
        && (combinacao[2] != combinacao[11])
        && (combinacao[2] != combinacao[12])
        && (combinacao[2] != combinacao[13])
        && (combinacao[2] != combinacao[14])
        && (combinacao[2] != combinacao[15])
        && (combinacao[2] != combinacao[16])
        && (combinacao[2] != combinacao[17])
        && (combinacao[2] != combinacao[18])
        && (combinacao[2] != combinacao[19])
        && (combinacao[3] != combinacao[4])
        && (combinacao[3] != combinacao[5])
        && (combinacao[3] != combinacao[6])
        && (combinacao[3] != combinacao[7])
        && (combinacao[3] != combinacao[8])
        && (combinacao[3] != combinacao[9])
        && (combinacao[3] != combinacao[10])
        && (combinacao[3] != combinacao[11])
        && (combinacao[3] != combinacao[12])
        && (combinacao[3] != combinacao[13])
        && (combinacao[3] != combinacao[14])
        && (combinacao[3] != combinacao[15])
        && (combinacao[3] != combinacao[16])
        && (combinacao[3] != combinacao[17])
        && (combinacao[3] != combinacao[18])
        && (combinacao[3] != combinacao[19])
        && (combinacao[4] != combinacao[5])
        && (combinacao[4] != combinacao[6])
        && (combinacao[4] != combinacao[7])
        && (combinacao[4] != combinacao[8])
        && (combinacao[4] != combinacao[9])
        && (combinacao[4] != combinacao[10])
        && (combinacao[4] != combinacao[11])
        && (combinacao[4] != combinacao[12])
        && (combinacao[4] != combinacao[13])
        && (combinacao[4] != combinacao[14])
        && (combinacao[4] != combinacao[15])
        && (combinacao[4] != combinacao[16])
        && (combinacao[4] != combinacao[17])
        && (combinacao[4] != combinacao[18])
        && (combinacao[4] != combinacao[19])
        && (combinacao[5] != combinacao[6])
        && (combinacao[5] != combinacao[7])
        && (combinacao[5] != combinacao[8])
        && (combinacao[5] != combinacao[9])
        && (combinacao[5] != combinacao[10])
        && (combinacao[5] != combinacao[11])
        && (combinacao[5] != combinacao[12])
        && (combinacao[5] != combinacao[13])
        && (combinacao[5] != combinacao[14])
        && (combinacao[5] != combinacao[15])
        && (combinacao[5] != combinacao[16])
        && (combinacao[5] != combinacao[17])
        && (combinacao[5] != combinacao[18])
        && (combinacao[5] != combinacao[19])
        && (combinacao[6] != combinacao[7])
        && (combinacao[6] != combinacao[8])
        && (combinacao[6] != combinacao[9])
        && (combinacao[6] != combinacao[10])
        && (combinacao[6] != combinacao[11])
        && (combinacao[6] != combinacao[12])
        && (combinacao[6] != combinacao[13])
        && (combinacao[6] != combinacao[14])
        && (combinacao[6] != combinacao[15])
        && (combinacao[6] != combinacao[16])
        && (combinacao[6] != combinacao[17])
        && (combinacao[6] != combinacao[18])
        && (combinacao[6] != combinacao[19])
        && (combinacao[7] != combinacao[8])
        && (combinacao[7] != combinacao[9])
        && (combinacao[7] != combinacao[10])
        && (combinacao[7] != combinacao[11])
        && (combinacao[7] != combinacao[12])
        && (combinacao[7] != combinacao[13])
        && (combinacao[7] != combinacao[14])
        && (combinacao[7] != combinacao[15])
        && (combinacao[7] != combinacao[16])
        && (combinacao[7] != combinacao[17])
        && (combinacao[7] != combinacao[18])
        && (combinacao[7] != combinacao[19])
        && (combinacao[8] != combinacao[9])
        && (combinacao[8] != combinacao[10])
        && (combinacao[8] != combinacao[11])
        && (combinacao[8] != combinacao[12])
        && (combinacao[8] != combinacao[13])
        && (combinacao[8] != combinacao[14])
        && (combinacao[8] != combinacao[15])
        && (combinacao[8] != combinacao[16])
        && (combinacao[8] != combinacao[17])
        && (combinacao[8] != combinacao[18])
        && (combinacao[8] != combinacao[19])
        && (combinacao[9] != combinacao[10])
        && (combinacao[9] != combinacao[11])
        && (combinacao[9] != combinacao[12])
        && (combinacao[9] != combinacao[13])
        && (combinacao[9] != combinacao[14])
        && (combinacao[9] != combinacao[15])
        && (combinacao[9] != combinacao[16])
        && (combinacao[9] != combinacao[17])
        && (combinacao[9] != combinacao[18])
        && (combinacao[9] != combinacao[19])
        && (combinacao[10] != combinacao[11])
        && (combinacao[10] != combinacao[12])
        && (combinacao[10] != combinacao[13])
        && (combinacao[10] != combinacao[14])
        && (combinacao[10] != combinacao[15])
        && (combinacao[10] != combinacao[16])
        && (combinacao[10] != combinacao[17])
        && (combinacao[10] != combinacao[18])
        && (combinacao[10] != combinacao[19])
        && (combinacao[11] != combinacao[12])
        && (combinacao[11] != combinacao[13])
        && (combinacao[11] != combinacao[14])
        && (combinacao[11] != combinacao[15])
        && (combinacao[11] != combinacao[16])
        && (combinacao[11] != combinacao[17])
        && (combinacao[11] != combinacao[18])
        && (combinacao[11] != combinacao[19])
        && (combinacao[12] != combinacao[13])
        && (combinacao[12] != combinacao[14])
        && (combinacao[12] != combinacao[15])
        && (combinacao[12] != combinacao[16])
        && (combinacao[12] != combinacao[17])
        && (combinacao[12] != combinacao[18])
        && (combinacao[12] != combinacao[19])
        && (combinacao[13] != combinacao[14])
        && (combinacao[13] != combinacao[15])
        && (combinacao[13] != combinacao[16])
        && (combinacao[13] != combinacao[17])
        && (combinacao[13] != combinacao[18])
        && (combinacao[13] != combinacao[19])
        && (combinacao[14] != combinacao[15])
        && (combinacao[14] != combinacao[16])
        && (combinacao[14] != combinacao[17])
        && (combinacao[14] != combinacao[18])
        && (combinacao[14] != combinacao[19])
        && (combinacao[15] != combinacao[16])
        && (combinacao[15] != combinacao[17])
        && (combinacao[15] != combinacao[18])
        && (combinacao[15] != combinacao[19])
        && (combinacao[16] != combinacao[17])
        && (combinacao[16] != combinacao[18])
        && (combinacao[16] != combinacao[19])
        && (combinacao[17] != combinacao[18])
        && (combinacao[17] != combinacao[19])
        && (combinacao[18] != combinacao[19])
) {
```

Comment: O ponto principal aqui é que não é suposto você fazer 200 comparações no mesmo `if`. A solução é percorrer o vetor e ir comparando e construindo o resultado

Answer (score 5):

Este código faz EXATAMENTE a mesma coisa do código que está ai escrito, só que usando laços, você poderia implementar desta forma em seu código:

```
    boolean semRepeticoes = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < combinacao.length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < combinacao.length; j++)
        {
            if (!(semRepeticoes = combinacao[i] != combinacao[j] || i == j))
                break;
        }
        if (!semRepeticoes)
            break;
    }
    if (semRepeticoes)
        System.out.println("não existem repetições");
    else
        System.out.println("Existem números repetidos no Array");
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, sou leigo no java ainda. Neste script que me passou ele apresenta uma das duas mensagens, eu sei que terão numeros repetidos. Mas quero que ele imprima somente os que não são combinações repetidas